# How configure multiple files using logstash.conf file

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am going to configure all log files present in location(D:\Logs **folder**)

log files are

1.Magna_Log4Net.log.20150623_bak

2.Magna_Log4Net.log.20150624_bak

3.Magna_Log4Net.log.20150625_bak

4.Magna_Log4Net.log.20150626_bak

**logstash.conf file**

```js
   input { 

    file {

        path =["C:\Test\Logs\Magna_Log4Net.log.*_bak"]

     start_position => "beginning" 
      }
   }

filter {

  grok { match => [ "message", "%{HTTPDATE:[@metadata][timestamp]}" ] }

  date { match => [ "[@metadata][timestamp]", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ] }

}

output {

  elasticsearch { host => localhost}

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}
```

[image: elasticsearch webUI]

I am not able to load all files into elastic search , I didn't understand the problem here. can any body help to to how to parse multiple files into logstash config files ???

Comment: I want to load all 4 logstash's into Elasticsearch UI

Comment: What happens?  Did you try increasing debugging?

Comment: Alain Collins, after so many trial and error methods, finally i got the solution...i.e, change the path to   path =["C:/Test/Logs/Magna_Log4Net.log.*_bak"]